# root mean square deviation value using kabsch

Tags: matrices

i've got myself to a problem, where i am implementing [Kabsch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kabsch_algorithm) to calculate root-mean-square-deviation.
I'm using two matrices to get a rotation and translation matrices. [(Java implementation i'm using)](http://jonasdevlieghere.com/software/kabsch-algorithm-implemented-java-using-ejml)

> A(4)(3)

and

> B(4)(3)

=> Kabsch gives:
Translation matrix -

> Translation(4)(1)

Rotation matrix -

> Rotation(3)(3)

What do i do next? How do i calculate rmsd and if i should modify A or B matrices using translation or rotation matrices?

Sorry for not giving perfect explanation.